# Application could not execute because of shared library issue

Tags: linux, shared-library

I am trying to execute an ARM application which uses ffmpeg's ".so" libraries. I ran this application on the ARM board and it gave me error "error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".

After that I moved the libraries to the board and exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the library path. Because of this it didn't give me an error.

But after running this it didn't give me any initial prints that I had put in at the start of the main function. The application was just coming out without doing any execution.

I thought it was due to shared libraries. Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: How about using `gdb` or `strace` to debug your app?  The latter often gives important clues on how it gets to those circumstances.